# C# MVC RedirectToAction not updating View

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a C# MVC website which has a controller that has multiple ActionResult methods inside of it. I have the basic Index which just loads the initial page which has a form on it. The user fills out this form and clicks submit. From there the form is serialized and send to the method directly below which does some stuff then redirects to another action.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GenerateDegreeAudit(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        //Do Stuff

        //Then
        return RedirectToAction("Review");
    }
```

The Review method, shown below, is getting hit by my breakpoint.

```
    public ActionResult Review()
    {
        ViewBag.Courses = DegreeAuditRequest.Courses;
        return View();
    }
```

As is the corresponding Review.cshtml file shown below.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="box box-primary">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Review", "DegreeAuditProcess", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @role = "form", @id = "frmReview" }))
        {
        <div class="box-body">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var course in ViewBag.Courses)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="@course.EventName" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="@course.ScheduledTerm" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
            <div class="box-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div style="width: 100%;">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generate" id="btnDAPRocess" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

However the page doesn't update to show the HTML on the Review.cshtml file. What am I missing?

Comment: While debugging `Review` controller action method, can you see data in `DegreeAuditRequest.Courses`? If so, try casting `course` in your view. It could be that `@course` it's returning an Object type instead of Course, hence it can't get access to `@course.EventName`.

Comment: You're saying the browser is not displaying any of that HTML at all? I am not sure if you shared the whole Razor file, but, for starters, I am not seeing any `<html>` tag, nor a reference to a layout that might have one...

Comment: I believe `DegreeAuditRequest` is a controller level property. When you redirect from one action to another, property initialized in one action will not be available in other action. Did you debug and check if `DegreeAuditRequest.Courses` has values in it?

Comment: @derloopkat Yes, the DegreeAuditRequest.Courses object did indeed have courses in it. It was pulling the EventName just fine when in debug mode. That's why I'm confused. Everything looks like it worked properly.

Comment: Can you tell us what the page does show when you perform the redirect? Does it show a clear screen or does nothing change on the page? Have you checked the dev tools console to see if there any issue with the request?

Comment: @KingOfArrows There's no issues with the request that show in the dev tools. Nothing appears to happen on the page at all. :(

Comment: Looking up above and you said it worked fine in debug mode. Is the error occurring only in Release mode?

Comment: Hi, when redirecting to Review, if DegreeAuditRequest.Courses  data is generated in GenerateDegreeAudit, you can pass it as the second parameter e.g. return RedirectToAction("Review",DegreeAuditRequest); so you can have access to it in the Review action. Also in the Review action method, it should be passed as a parameter e.g. public ActionResult Review(DegreeAuditRequest DegreeAuditRequest) {...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is incredibly obnoxious. It has to do with how the initial form was submitted. In order to hit GenerateDegreeAudit I was not using form.submit but rather using an Ajax call. Because of this MVC handles Ajax completely different from how it handles form.submit. Using form.submit works just fine.